# How To Pass Lists of data from C# to MySQL Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a MySQL stored procedure that is called from a C# MVC project, that will take in a number of parameters to make a hotel reservation.

The problem I've come across is that for MySQL Stored Procedures what is the best approach to pass lists of objects.

One idea I had was before calling the stored procedure, I could pre-save the required data in some temp tables, and use a unique key that can be called in the Stored Procedure making the hotel reservation where it can grabs all the data from temp tables.

You might ask, why don't I just call multiple stored procedures, but for integrity purposes, I will be using MySQL Transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You might ask, why don't I just call multiple stored procedures, but for integrity purposes, I will be using MySQL Transactions.

That's an interesting reason. Consider the following code:

```
using (MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("cstring"))
{
    c.Open();
    var t = c.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        foreach (var o in list)
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("EXECUTE sp @field1, @field2", c, t))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", o.field1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", o.field2);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        t.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        t.Rollback();
        // do something with ex
    }
}
```

that is **one contiguous transaction with multiple trips to the database.** Though I don't fully understand your application, load, or requirements, it seems to me that if you simply do something like this it will work just fine for your needs. The only time the number of round-trips start to matter is when you're dealing with *millions* of transactions.

Comment: Is it possible to use this in a similar way but by calling Stored Procedures and not MySQlCommands

Comment: @Tommo1977, you don't **have** to use parameterized SQL statements, you could of course just string together the command and send it in raw, but that's **not good**, even if this is just an internal application. You want to practice how you play - and you don't want to play with SQL injection.